# Use PHP to pull values from HTML forms and store them in MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, webforms

I seem to have a bit of a problem here that I can't quite figure out.

So the deal is I have a php script along with an HTML file, in that file I have a few forms with some text boxes and some drop downs. Now the reason I had to go single forms on all of these was because if I did one big one none of them would work when I would hit the submit button. I have no idea... My current code is below, my previous code only had one form and it wouldn't work at all.

```
          <form method="post" id="locationFromPost" name="locationFormPost">
                                <div class="formRow">
                                    <div class="label">
                                        <label for="locationForm">Current Location:</label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="field">
                                            //If post is null go back to value pull originally else echo post           
                                               <?php if($_POST['locationForm']==null) $location=$location;else $location=$_POST['locationForm']; ?>             
                                        <input type="text" name="locationForm" id="locationForm" value="<?php echo $location?>"></input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

...... and so on.......

```
           <form method="post" id="sexFromPost" name="sexFormPost">    
                          <div class="formRow">
                                <div class="label">
                                    <label for="sexForm">Sex</label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="dropDown">
                                    <select name="sex" id="sexForm" >
//If post is null go back to value pull originally else echo post                                   
                              <?php if($_POST['sexForm']==null) $sex=$sex;else $sex=$_POST['sexForm']; ?>
                                        <option value="1" <?php if($sex==1){echo"selected='selected'";}?>>Male</option>
                                        <option value="2" <?php if($sex==2){echo"selected='selected'";}?>>Female</option>
                                        <option value="3" <?php if($sex==3){echo"selected='selected'";}?>>Not Specified</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                             </div>
            </form>
```

...... and so on.......

```
    <form method="post" id="submit" name="submit">
    <div class="formRow"><div id="seperator"></div></div>
                    <div class="submitButton">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save Changes"/> 
                    </div>          
                </div>
</form>
```

So thats what the top part of my code looks like, all the div's are for formatting you don't have to worry about those. Now the php code to save the information is below. I should note that the variables you see in the php parts of the code above are retrieved from the Database in the earlier part of the code, thats working fine. What I am having problems with is I want a user to be able to edit their information then just hit the submit button and the information to be saved. What currently happens is, well, absolutely noting. The page will refresh and all the values will go back to what they were when they were pulled, they are not stored in the DB at all, now I checked to make for sure that part of the code works, buy doing some test. It saves the data no problem. What I thin is the problem is the forms them-selfs, if I do everything in one big form it doesn't work... Don't know why. now if I hit enter at the end of each of the forms individually in the browser the data goes in but just that field, sometimes other fields are wiped completely out and a null or empty string is stored. I cant seem to figure this thing out at all.

heres the php to save the information.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET location= '".$_POST['locationForm']."' WHERE usr='" .mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['usr']) ."'");
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET location= '".$_POST['sexForm']."' WHERE usr='" .mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['usr']) ."'");

........ you know the rest.......
}?>
```

I am completely lost at why this thing is doing this, now im not the best PHP programmer by any-means, so it could (probably is) be me. If anyone could point out what I would need to do to get a system like that working please let me know

Thanks.

Comment: First of all, escape your sql query variables. But second of all, only one form can be submitted at a time. You need all the form fields inside a single form if you want them all to be submitted at once. Millions of websites have managed this, so there's an actual error in your handling of the form rather than "it doesn't work, so I split it."

Comment: Okay, thanks for your input, I have actually done that same thing on another page, however I just couldn't get it to work on this one. Ill keep trying. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't clear exactly what your problem was.

However this:

```
 <?php if($_POST['locationForm']==null) $location=$location;else $location=$_POST['locationForm']; ?>
```

Doesn't look to me like it is going to do much. Try something like this:

```
<?php 
    if(!isset($_POST['locationForm'])){
       $location=$location;
    }
   else {
       $location=$_POST['locationForm'];
    } 
?>
```

(Curly braces are my own personal liking)

Assuming you have $location defined somewhere you didn't show us. This will check if there is NOT a $_POST['locationForm'], and if there is it will use it.

Comment: ahh okay, I see what your doing there, and yeah $location is defined elsewhere, ill give that a try, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing all the form fields within on form tag and also use `mysql_real_escape_string` on your variable as well.

Answer (score 0):

you need all the fields that are going to be submitted to any given page to exist in a single form tag. any elements in a different form tag will submit as a set of THAT form tag. 
I' assuming that you also want to maybe combine down your updates?

```
//$_SESSION['usr'] should already be sanitized and safed wherever you handle your site credentials..
//set your submittable values, with a default to an empty string in this case.

$sex=isset($_POST['sexForm'])?mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sexForm']):"";
$location=isset($_POST['locationForm'])?mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['locationForm']):"";

//single statement, no need to iterate for each field, that's wasted connections.
$sql="update "UPDATE members SET location= '$location' , sex='$sex' WHERE  usr='".$_SESSION['usr']."'";
```